# Airplane mode is on whenever I suspend my device and won't turn off

Tags: networking, suspend, airplane-mode

I’ve recently installed Ubuntu on my HP laptop and I went through the setup flawlessly. I started to realize that whenever I suspend my Ubuntu it literally stops me from enabling WiFi which is understandable, but for some reason it won’t let me disable airplane mode.

I also tried using this command `rfkill list all` and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

The results gave me

```
phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

```
       08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 81)
        DeviceName: IntelWLAN Intel 3165NGWG Stone Peak 1 ac 1x1 + BT 4 LE PCIe+USB NGFF 2230WW
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165 [8086:4010]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Not sure if this is helpful, but maybe it is, also I realized that restarting my device fixes the issue. It is incredibly annoying having to restart every time if my computer gets suspended. As Far as I know my laptop does not have a physical switch to turn on wireless internet, in fact my Windows runs fine and never gets stuck in airplane mode.

Also I am running on a Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and using a HP Pavillion Notebook with intel hd graphics and a i5 dual core.

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using? Hard blocked usual means a physical switch has been turned off, you may want to look into that.

Comment: Fast Reply I edited it can you check again

Comment: I tried checking my laptop and I don’t really see a switch except a switch to open up my laptop

Comment: More likely it's a (Function) key or a key combo (FN+Fsomething).

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'm not sure about my, but whenever I press FN on every F12 or F5,etc. It does not work, further more I pressed my airplane mode button and it still does not work. It says something whenever I press it, it just says "Hardware...", it just stops at "Hardware". I have checked into my BIOS setup too and I don't see any wireless related things, I have even tried other distro's and I get the same result. It's like it only occurs on Linux.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have edited my question, can you check?

Comment: You WiFi device is perfectly supported and has been for many years. Driver is mentioned correctly. So, again, you need to toggle off airplane mode and probably wait a few second for the WiFi to be re-enabled and scan for networks. There's nothing else to it other than the hardware switch as commented before.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I’ll try that maybe it would work I keep spamming airplane mode not giving chance for it to reconnect, though its akward since it does not happen on Windows.

Comment: My airplane mode only disables and enables soft blocks